# Nextjs: how to display the price of a product in a component header when you click on the product

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am new with Nextjs(React).
I created two components header.tsx and product.tsx. I call them in a file (components) stepperLine.tsx
I actually want to display the price of the product in the header.tsx component when I click "choose" on the product
I tried many times but I can't do it. Same with ChatGPT. I hope you can help me please.

See below to further understand my concern.

My component `Header.tsx`: This is where I want to display the price of the product when I click.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { Stepper } from 'react-form-stepper';
import { IoArrowBack } from 'react-icons/io5'

const Header = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    return (
        <>
            <div className="fixed w-full bg-white top-0">
                <div className="flex items-center justify-between shadow-lg px-4 shadow-black-100">
                    <div>
                        <button type="button"
                                onClick={() => router.push('/')}
                                className='text-sm flex items-center font-semibold bg-transparent py-1.5 px-3 lg:px-7.5 navbutton rounded-full hover:bg-navyblue hover:text-white'>
                            <IoArrowBack className='mr-2'/>
                            Back to home
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex-auto w-64">
                        <Stepper
                            steps={[{}, {}, {}]}
                            activeStep={2}
                            className="font-bold text-sm"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <span className="font-bold text-xl border rounded-full border-black hover:border-green-500 hover:text-white cursor-pointer hover:bg-green-500 px-4">
                        {/* this is where i want to show the price */}
                         {String.fromCharCode(8355)}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

My component `Product.tsx`: the price is displayed nice and beautiful here.
It's just for testing to see it works.
But I want to display it in the header.

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import { AiOutlineCheckCircle } from 'react-icons/ai'
import data from '../../data/infographie.json';
import React from "react";

const Product = () => {

    const [product, setProduct] = React.useState(0);

    const choiseProduct = (priceProduct: number) => {
        setProduct(priceProduct)
        console.log(product)
    };
 
    return (
        <>
          <div className="grid gridCard grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
              {
                data.map((items, i) => (
                    <div className='rounded-lg hover:outline-none hover:skew-x-1
                                transition-all hover:scale-80 hover:-translate-y-1 hover:ring-2 hover:ring-green-400 shadow flex flex-col justify-between hover:bg-green-50 hover:shadow-xl'
                                >
                      <Image width={300} height={300} className="h-54 max-w-full rounded-lg" src={items.image} alt="" />
                      <div className='mt-2'>
                          <span className="font-bold text-2xl m-6">{items.name}</span>
                          <button type="button" onClick={()=>choiseProduct(items.prix_unitaire)} className='text-sm m-4 flex items-center justify-center font-semibold bg-transparent py-1.5 px-3 lg:px-7.5 navbutton rounded-full hover:bg-navyblue hover:text-white'>
                           <AiOutlineCheckCircle className='mr-2' />
                               Choose
                          </button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                    ))
               }
            </div>
             {/* the price is displayed nice and beautiful here. It's just for testing to see it works.*/}
            {product && (
                <span className="price p-4 bg-green text-white-font-bold">Prix: {product}</span>
             )}
        </>

    )
}

export  default Product;
```

My component for call the others two components: `StepperLine.tsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Header './header'
import Product './categories/product'
import User './categories/user'

const StepperLine = () => {
  
  const router = useRouter();
  let contentComponent;

  if (router.pathname === '/product') {
    contentComponent = <Product/>;
  } else if (router.pathname === '/user') {
    contentComponent = <User/>;
  }

  return (
      <>
          <Header/>
          {contentComponent}
      </>
  )
  
}
export default StepperLine;
```

**I hope to find help.
THANK YOU.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways that spring to mind:

- Using a setter prop.
- Using [context](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usecontext.asp) hook
- Using [redux](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-redux-tutorial-examples/#:%7E:text=Server%2Dside%20rendering-,What%20is%20Redux%3F,other%20JavaScript%20framework%20or%20library.)

Redux is overkill for a small project like this but worth keeping in mind if you intend to build something more complex.

Context and Setter prop work in a similar way by lifting state to the highest parent component. I will give you a quick idea of how the setter prop works and leave you to research the other options.

Declare a state variable in StepperLine as it is the parent of both Product and Header:

```
const [price, setPrice] = React.useState();
```

Then modify the product component to include the setter as a prop. This allows the product to update the parent state:

```
const Product = ({priceSetter}) => { ...
```

Also modify choiseProduct to use or new setter prop:

```
priceSetter(priceProduct);
```

Back in StepperLine, link the state variable to the new prop on Product:

```
contentComponent = <Product priceSetter={setPrice}/>;
```

Now simply pass the state from StepperLine into the Header component. Add a prop to Header:

```
const Header = (price) => { ...
```

And modify StepperLine to pass the state to Header component:

```
return (
  <>
      <Header price={price}/>
      {contentComponent}
  </>
```

Finally in the Header component you just need to display the price

```
<span className="font-bold text-xl border rounded-full border-black hover:border-green-500 hover:text-white cursor-pointer hover:bg-green-500 px-4">
                    {/* this is where i want to show the price */}
                     {price}
                </span>
```

I have not tested this code but hopefully this is enough detail to get you started.

Comment: Thanks verry much. Its work now with your instructions.

```const Header = ({price}: any) => { ...```